# Rails 4 routing concern with url parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In Rails 4, how I can create a routing concern that accepts a URL parameter? I have the following in my routes file:

```
concern :votable do
  get 'vote/:vote_type'
end

resources :parking_locations, concerns: :votable
```

I want to be able to hit URLs like the following:

```
/parking_locations/123/vote/0
/parking_locations/123/vote/1
/parking_locations/123/vote/2
```

However, I when I try to initialize my application, I get the following error:

```
Missing :action key on routes definition, please check your routes.
```

If I change the concern to just:

```
concern :votable do
  get 'vote'
end
```

Then the application works correctly and routes to the controllers `vote` method, but of course I no longer have a way to pass the `vote_type` in the URL.  Is it possible to set up a concern that accepts a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error describes, you need to specify the `:action` to hit. The following should work

```
concern :votable do
  get 'vote/:vote_type', action: :vote
end

resources :parking_locations, concerns: :votable
```

This will hit the `vote` action of the `ParkingLocationsController` and you'll have access to the `vote_type` param.